# Ubuntu 14.04 - takes ages to connect to wifi

Tags: wireless

It takes at least 5 minutes before my machine eventually connects to wifi.
Really don't know where to start so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please start here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I ran the script but I am somehow reluctant to post all these information about my system in a public forum. Is there any specific fields in the output I should be looking for ?

Comment: The problem seems to be more specific to certain wireless networks i.e. fine to connect at home but unable to at work

Comment: Did you look at the report output? Feel free to obscure any details you find sensitive. I suggest that you post it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com We will find it difficult to help you without a single clue as to your wireless driver, kernel version, settings, etc.

Comment: Working again for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You can try use Wifi Radar. [Download here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wifi-radar/)